# How to customize x axis tick labels for ggplot2 object created by plot() method

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use `ggeffects::ggemmeans()` to get predictions for a model. The output of `ggemmeans()` is of class `"ggeffects"`, and there's a `plot()` method for quickly visualizing the prediction. Although the resulted visualization is a `ggplot` object, I can't customize the labels of the x axis ticks.

### Example

```r
library(emmeans)
library(ggeffects)
#> Warning: package 'ggeffects' was built under R version 4.0.4
library(ggplot2)

my_model <- lm(mpg ~ factor(am), mtcars)
my_ggemmeans <- ggemmeans(my_model, terms = "am")
p <- plot(my_ggemmeans)

p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Problem

**I want to edit the labels of x axis ticks to replace `1` and `0` with "manual" and "automatic"**

Although `p` is a ggplot object:

```r
> is.ggplot(p)
[1] TRUE
```

I can't use `scale_x_discrete()`. For example:

```r
p +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("manual", "automatic"))
```

Returns the following warning:

> Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.

and the undesired plot:

[image]

What happened to the x axis tick labels?

**Bottom line**: how can I operate on `p` to replace the x axis tick labels?

---

EDIT

---

@Ronak's answer below suggests to rely on `scale_x_continuous()` and supply both `breaks` and `labels` arguments. However, this solution lacks "specificity". We can't pass a named vector to `labels` argument in `scale_x_continuous()` the way we can with `scale_x_discrete()` ([see reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63367190/6105259)). This means that the code

```r
p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c(`1` = "number one", `0` = "number zero"))
```

Gives mismatched labels:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `scale_x_continuous` :

```
p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c("manual", "automatic"))
```

[image]

It still gives the message that it is replacing the previous scale with the new one.

Comment: Thank you! Interestingly, I can't rename properly using a named vector. If I do `p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c(\`1\` = "number one", \`0\` = "number zero"))` I get the labels by the simple order inside `c()`, rather than by the names.

Comment: I don't think `labels` supports named vectors like that. I don't seem them mentioned in ?scale_x_continuous.

Comment: @TJMahr, the thing is that `scale_x_**discrete**()` does support a named vector for `labels` argument... also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63367190/6105259)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it answers the main question in the post. I'll post a separate question regarding the `labels` argument.