# In ggplot, how to map axis tick labels to a designated data column of labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When plotting with `ggplot()`, is there a way to map x/y tick labels to a designated column in the data? Currently, the only way I know is by creating a named vector of new <=> old axis labels, then feeding it into `scale_x/y_discrete(labels = ...)`.

Below is a very minimal example to convey this issue.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2021)

my_df <- 
  data.frame(name = c("animal_1", "animal_2", "animal_3"),
             value = runif(3),
             label = c("dog", "cat", "zebra"))

p <- 
  ggplot(my_df, aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

p
```

[image]

```r
#####
# editing x axis tick labels
## the way I currently know is by creating a separate *named* vector of labels
vector_of_labels <- dplyr::pull(my_df, label, name)
vector_of_labels
#> animal_1 animal_2 animal_3 
#>    "dog"    "cat"  "zebra"

p +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = vector_of_labels)
```

[image]

```r
## why can't we map the labels from my_df[["label"]] 
## using `aes()` into scale_x_discrete()?
p +
  scale_x_discrete(aes(label = labels))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

Is there a straightforward way to avoid the need to create a separate named vector, given that we do have a designated label column in the data?

Comment: To answer the question about why we can't map labels from the dataframe with `aes()` to a scale; there is no guarantee that the length in the data.frame corresponds to the length of the computed breaks due to duplicates in a data.frame. Furthermore, how would you expect this to integrate with a plot where the data is from multiple data.frames? In this specific case, I don't see why you wouldn't use `aes(x = label)`  in the geometry layer.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly. Why not just use the label column directly instead of “name”?

Comment: @teunbrand, thanks for the comment. Typically, the levels in my `x` variable are in English (such as `animal_1`), whereas in the final plot I seek to replace those levels with names from another language. My preference is to avoid computing or dealing with non-English characters. I rather to leave the non-English part to the very end, only for labeling.

Comment: But given it's impossible to achieve this in the way I asked about, then nevermind :)

Comment: Doesn't `scale_x_discrete(labels = my_df$label)` work for you, worked for me.

Comment: @norie, thanks. It works in this very specific example, but is error-prone in other cases because it's dependent on the order of value in the vector to match the order of values in the plot. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63366733/overriding-discrete-x-axis-labels-in-a-fool-proof-way-to-avoid-mismatching-label).

Comment: @Emman, I think that your solution of the named vector works the best. If you want to handle it at the end, you could wrap the plot in a function, which would require only entering the appropriate data frame once.

Comment: erm - why don't you just create a new column that contains the respective labels, then use this as x?

Comment: @tjebo, I've answered teunbrand about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68922838/in-ggplot-how-to-map-axis-tick-labels-to-a-designated-data-column-of-labels?noredirect=1#comment121807670_68922838). Although I guess I'll need to bring a convincing example for why dealing with non-English breaks things for me.